# If a sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is eventually non-negative and convergent, then the limit of the sequence is non-negative.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

My attempt at proving "if a sequence is convergent and eventually non-negative, then the limit of that sequence must be non-negative. Does it check out?

Let $(x_n)$ be convergent in R and let $∃m∈\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n≥0 \ ∀n≥m$. WTS $\lim⁡(x_n)=L≥0$.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $lim⁡(x_n )=L<0$.

Then $∀ε_o>0,∃k∈N$ s.t. if $n≥k$ then $|x_n-L|< ε_o$ (1)

Since we know (1) holds for all $ε_o>0$, it must hold for $ε_o= -L$.

Choose $ε_o≔-L$. Suppose $n≥\max⁡\{m,k\}$.

Then it follows from (1) that \begin{aligned}|x_n-L| &< ε_o
\\ L-ε_o <x_n &<L+ε_o  \\ x_n&<L+(-L) \\ x_n&<0
\end{aligned}

But we also have $x_n≥0$ since $n≥max⁡{\{m,k\}}≥m$. $⇒⇐$

Contradiction, therefore, we have $\lim(x_n)≥0$.

Comment: It's correct. But I would rather choose $\epsilon_{0}=\frac{-L}{2}$ to show that $x_{n}<\frac{L}{2}<0$ for $n$ large enough to give myself a bit more room and emphasize that it is indeed lesser than a fixed negative number rather than just being lesser than $0$.

Comment: Your proof is correct. For an equivalent but shorter one, see the answer to [Prove that a convergent sequence with non-negative terms converges to a non-negative limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367672/prove-that-a-convergent-sequence-with-non-negative-terms-converges-to-a-non-nega)

Comment: what means WTS? I didn't saw before this contraction. From [this list](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/WTS) the more appropriate seems to be "want to see", is that the case?

Comment: @Masacroso neither did I but probably "[we] Want To Show".